# Register Oracle Linux to Satellite 6

Tags: ansible, satellite, oel

OEL is an RPM based downstream project from RHEL; however, if you use ULN, subscription-manager an other pieces are missing, and cannot be loaded from OEL repositories.

How do you register OEL to Satellite 6 for content or at a minimum for Ansible plays?

In my situation, and this is completely ineligant, I had to 'steal' the following from RHEL to install, then register, then remove then re-install the ULN RHN stuff.

There has got to be a better way to do this...

```
# yum install -y python-{dateutil,six,inotify,setuptools}
# yum --downloaddir /tmp/ --downloaonly reinstall rhn-client-tools
# yum remove rhn-client-tools
# curl --insecure --output katello-ca-consumer-latest.noarch.rpm https://<capsule FQDN>/pub/katello-ca-consumer-<capsule FQDN>-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

Log on to a similarly versioned RHEL box and do a download of the following rpms:

```
other host# yum reinstall --downloadonly --downloaddir /tmp/ \
python-syspurpose \
subscription-manager{,-rhsm,-rhsm-certificates}
```

Move (scp) those files to the location you had katello-ca-consumer file located on the OEL server.

Now do the installation

```
# yum localinstall ./python* ./subscr* ./katel*
```

Register the host

```
# subscription-manager register --org="<organization>" --activationkey=<key>
```

Remove subscription-manager (won't work with ULN)

```
# yum -y remove subscription-manager
```

Reinstall ULN

```
# yum localinstall -y ./rhn-client-tools-*
```

At this point, you can run ansible and commands (sh) agains the host, even including it in your hourly ansible roles application if you want.

However, since OEL is RPM based, is there not a more straightforward approach to this? Alma and CentOS you just execute subscription-manager and you are on your way...

Comment: Regarding "_OEL is an RPM based downstream project from RHEL_" and "_is there not a more straightforward approach to this?_", you may take note that Unbreakable Linux Network (ULN) and Oracle Enterprise Linux (OEL) belongs to the company Oracle. It is a product from them which they selling and providing support for, whereby the Red Hat Network (RHN) belongs to Red Hat / IBM. See also [About the ULN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/uln-user/ol_about_uln.html), [RHN Overview](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_network/5.0.0).